Why aren’t cookies and cache persisting in QWebEngineProfile (Qt 6.8.1)?
I’m currently developing a browser-like application using Qt 6.8.1 and C++. My goal is to enable persistent cookies and cache so that website logins (e.g., Gmail or Microsoft accounts) remain active after restarting the application. However, despite my setup, cookies are not preserved, and all logins are forgotten.
I’ve implemented a QWebEngineProfile with a persistent storage path and cache path, using ForcePersistentCookies. I’ve also enabled local storage and other relevant settings. Below is my attempt:
QWebEngineProfile *PersistentProfile = new QWebEngineProfile(this);
QString storagePath = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation) + QStringLiteral("/PersistentProfile");

if (!QDir(storagePath).exists()) {
    QDir().mkpath(storagePath);
}

PersistentProfile->setPersistentStoragePath(storagePath);
PersistentProfile->setCachePath(storagePath);
PersistentProfile->setPersistentCookiesPolicy(QWebEngineProfile::ForcePersistentCookies);
PersistentProfile->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::LocalStorageEnabled, true);
PersistentProfile->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, true);
PersistentProfile->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::XSSAuditingEnabled, false);

QWebEnginePage *profilepage = new QWebEnginePage(PersistentProfile, this);
QWebEngineView *webView = new QWebEngineView(this);
webView->setPage(profilepage);

I’ve reviewed GitHub bug reports but couldn’t determine if this behavior is a known limitation of QWebEngineProfile in Qt 6.8.1 or if there’s an issue with my code.
Questions:

Am I using the correct approach to enable persistent cookies and cache with QWebEngineProfile?

How can I verify whether cookies and cache are being written to the storage path?

Are there additional steps required to achieve what I’m attempting?


I’m relatively new to C++ and Qt programming, so I’d appreciate any guidance or resources to help me understand this better.

The QWebEngineProfile constructor you use "Constructs a new off-the-record profile... An off-the-record profile leaves no record on the local machine, and has no persistent data or cache." Try using the other constructor, the one that takes storageName parameter.

@IgorTandetnik Thank you. I redefined the constructor as QWebEngineProfile *PersistentProfile = new QWebEngineProfile(QStringLiteral("PersistentProfile"), this);, which seems to have partially solved the issue. However, I believe the storage path I am using is incorrectly defined as the application only retains the cookie and cache data when I explicitly set the storage path to a sub-folder within my project folder using QString storagePath = "/home/user/project/profile";, with profile being the sub-folder name. Is this the correct way I should define the storage path?
